# Unrecognized font-family '$text-font-family' - React-native CLI - ui-kitten - ios simulator

Tags: ios, react-native, fonts, react-native-cli, react-native-ui-kitten

I am developing my first react-native app using react-native CLI.
I have a working setup with android simulator on PC and I just got the simulator working on my Mac using cocoapods and xcode.

The issue I am having with the iphone simulation is that I get an error about font-family.

> "Unrecognized font family '$text-font-family'

I am using UI-kitten and I have confirmed that when I am using the react-native text component instead of the UI-kitten one I don't get the error.
I've been trying to find information about this error but it seems that usually a specific font can't be found.

I've tried to override the font-family used by UI-kitten by using a custom mapping described in their documentation here https://akveo.github.io/react-native-ui-kitten/docs/guides/branding#typography but the error remains.

Does anyone know of a solution to this?